# testing if boost::mpl::or_ evaluates to true or false

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

How would I test if `or_` evaluates to true or false?

say I have

```
typedef boost::mpl::or_<
    boost::is_same<ExPolicy,sequential_execution_policy>,
    boost::is_same<InIter, std::input_iterator_tag>,
    boost::is_same<OutIter, std::output_iterator_tag>
> is_seq;
```

how would I test the result? Currently I tried to do

```
auto h = is_seq();
if(h == boost::mpl::true_::value)
```

but everything evaluates to false when I know at least **one** case in my program is true. What can I do to know the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `is_seq::value`. For example:

```
template<typename T>
using type = boost::mpl::or_<
                std::is_same<T, char>,
                std::is_same<T, int>
             >;
int main() 
{
    std::cout << type<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << type<long>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47dd246711d6eb93)